# Deploy Symfony2 on Amazon Web Services

Tags: symfony, amazon-ec2, lamp

I am looking for some advices about deploying a Symfony2 web application. I got introduce to Amazon EC2 few days ago and we decided to use it to deploy our app.

Actually I am basically looking for a well set up AMI to get start. I have been quite disapointed that the Elastic Beanstalk doesn't have a native support for PHP based apps.

I have been developping on a wamp server and and my app will communicate with an Oracle database also in Amazon RDS (that's why we choose Amazon ).

I have checked this website http://bitnami.org/cloud/bitnami-applications-in-the-cloud that provides a Lamp stack. What do you think about it? The point is that I am not used to Unix base OS and I would appreciate an AMI that doesn't need many configurations.

Thanks,

Swordi

Answer (score 4):

Elastic Beanstalk [now provides direct support for PHP](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.html).

Comment: [There's a page on Symfony2 in the official Amazon docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_symfony2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Bitnamis CloudImages are pretty solid and well maintained, so it's an easy way to get your server up and running without too much headache as Unix beginner. Maybe their [Cloud Hosting](http://bitnami.org/cloud/) is an option, too.

On the other hand it's good to know what's powering your web applications and how this "stuff" works. Take a look at this article about building a LAMP on EC2: [Building EC2 Amazon Linux with LAMP](http://jonathanhui.com/building-ec2-amazon-linux-lamp).

You can also go with this tutorial:
["Running phpMyAdmin On Nginx (LEMP) on Debian Squeeze / Ubuntu"](http://www.howtoforge.com/running-phpmyadmin-on-nginx-lemp-on-debian-squeeze-ubuntu-11.04) in conjunction with [Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/Cloud/AmazonEC2Image) or [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide#Official_Ubuntu_Cloud_Guest_Amazon_Machine_Images_.28AMIs.29) CloudImages.

Hope that helps :)